# ExtJS 3: how to select row in Ext.grid.GridView having object of class x-grid3-cell-inner using fireEvent

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events

I have an object of `Ext.grid.GridView` class with rows in it. Rows have class x-grid3-cell-inner. I want to select row in GridView using fireEvent methods.
So, for example, I write code (I have id of first cell):

```
var e = document.createEventObject(); 
e.button = 0; 
var o = document.getElementById('id'); 
o.fireEvent('OnMouseDown', e);
```

But nothing happens. I tried to do that for button and it works, but it doesn't work for row in Ext.grid.GridView. Can somebody tell me how to select row in that ExtJS Grid using DOM events?
P.S. I cannot use Ext object to work with grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a listener for `onmousedown` in the code. I can see one for `click`. You could try that.

Why can't you use the Ext object, however? Seems like you could find the id of the cell, go up until you find the grid component's id, `Ext.getCmp` to get a reference to the grid component and then use the RowSelectionModel.

Comment: Thank you! Please,can you describe how can I do that? "grid component's id" it is component with class x-grid3-body? What I should do next? In that case I think I can use Ext object (I'm writing automated test for app and i can't change embedded js code, i can perform action through "eval"method of browser.)

Comment: Got it, thank you! Used Ext.getCmp then getSelectionModel(). Regarding event: it doesn't work, because I didin't specify "which=1" property for event.